# Widget rebuilds after TextField click

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am having an issue where the whole widget reloads when i just click on TextField.
I don't want this to happen.
Tried many ways but could not get to a solution.  I am running the app on an Android device.

```
class Testextends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
   final _search = TextEditingController();
   static final  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Container(
          height: 45,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[400]),
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(30.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400], fontSize: 15),
                    labelText: 'Search...',
                  ),
                  controller: _search,
                  onSubmitted: (_) => search(),
                ),
              ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  body: Text('Test Body'),
);
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this happen ?

Answer (score 1):

I think using [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) results in this behavior, as MediaQuery rebuilds the widget every time the dimensions change. The dimensions change as soon as the keyboard opens.